# Is it possible to add run list in a VM with the chef client only installed in it ??

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

We are having only the chef client installed in a machine and the chef workstation is also on the same machine. We can develop the cookbooks for that machine but we are not able to update the run list. Is it possible to update the run list and make it run on that VM ?
We do not have a chef server but we can setup the workstation on the same VM.

If yes how ?

Comment: Use Chef-zero to run locally.